# Please blacklist the [elementary-os] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

There are currently three questions tagged [elementary-os](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-os). This tag covers all questions, so it should be blacklisted as an intrinsic tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I removed the tag from two of the questions and accepted your suggested edit on the third. Then I added [elementary-os](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-os) as a blacklisted intrinsic tag. Good catch.

Comment: Could you do the same for the [tag:elementary] tag as well?

Comment: @waldyrious: That would be a good idea. Would you mind looking at the ["Start by cleaning up the edges" section of this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/1438)? In particular, if there are questions that only have that tag, we'll need to apply another tag at some point.

Comment: Sure. For future reference, I'll be using [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/elementaryos/query/429381/find-questions-with-one-specific-tag?tag=elementary) to locate such questions, based on the one of the queries linked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273840/how-to-search-questions-with-only-one-specific-tag).

Comment: Btw, while cleaning up those questions, I've come across at last a couple whose authors claim they weren't able to add an appropriate tag due to not having sufficient reputation (150, according to [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13290/retroarch-not-showing-after-installing-using-flatpak-on-elementary-os)). I suppose that expanding the list of existing tags should alleviate this issue, but let me know if there's any other action that could be taken, e.g. reconfiguring the reputation limits.

Comment: I believe I managed to clean up all the questions that were exclusively tagged with "elementary".

Comment: @waldyrious: Done. (Since it took me a few days, I see there were two more questions added that been a new question added that's now [untagged](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).) Generally, if users can't create the tag they need, they can leave a comment and someone else can add it. We can't really adjust the privilege levels for that.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make sure to improve the tag situation to help people avoid issues with tags. My plan is to work on detailed tag descriptions and appropriate synonyms. I can't do that yet, since I don't have sufficient reputation. (Unfortunately, Stack Exchange's reputation system seems to have been set up within a mindset of erecting barriers to prevent poor quality content, which often backfires by also blocking useful contributions...)

Comment: By the way, do you think it would make sense to also blacklist [tag:eos] and [tag:e-os], just in case? I've seen many people refer to the OS like that, and I can imagine people will try alternatives for the same reason they felt the need to use the [tag:elementary] tag.